# Left shift confusion with microcontroller compiler

Tags: microcontroller, c, debugging

Using an STM32 uC debugger, and from binary 0111 I want to obtain 1110. And to do so, I use left shift operator as follow:

```
uint8_t a =  0b00000111;
uint8_t b = (1<<a);
```

But for the variable b instead of 00001110(as I expect), the compiler gives the follwing:

> ```
> Decimal:-128  Hex:0x80    Binary:10000000
> ```

Where am I wrong here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should instead be performing:

```
b = a << 1;
```

Which would be bitshifting the value `a` by 1 bit to the left.

---

As it stands, you are asking for the value of `1`, to be shifted `a` bits to the left. As `a` is set to `7`, then the MCU is calculating `1 << 7`, which is 128 - equal to the 0x80 in hex you are seeing (*).

---

(*) Note that your debugger shows -128 in "Decimal" - I don't know what software you are using to print that value, but it is apparently converting `b` to a signed 8-bit integer for display. 0x80 represents -128 when stored as a signed `int8_t`.

Comment: I've been coding embedded C for 30 years, and I couldn't find the problem until you pointed it out. My brain automatically assumed that it was `a<<1` from the beginning!

Comment: Worth pointing out that the RHS of OP's assignment is signed because that `1` is a signed integer. Bit-shifting signed numbers is in general a bad idea (due to potential implicit sign extension leading to surprising results), although it's not the main issue here.

Answer (score 5):

In case of `a << b`, the meaning is "left shift a by b number of bits". So you should have done `a << 1` instead.

Instead you did `1 << 7` which gives 0x80 or 128 if you will. It does not give -128 for a variable with type `uint8_t` - your compiler/debugger is displaying using the wrong type. `uint8_t` always has a range from 0 to 255.

---

Best practices:

Please note that `1 << anything` is always dangerous, since  the `1` itself is a signed `int`. You should always use `1u <<` .

Also note that shifting a *small integer type* such as `uint8_t`, `char`, `short` etc is always dangerous too, since they get implicitly promoted to type `int` (See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)) and then we have the same problem as above. Best practices is to make an explicit cast of the left operand to the `unsigned int` type of your specific system. That is `(uint16_t)a << 1` on 8- and 16 bit microcontrollers, `(uint32_t)a << 1` on all other systems.

Be aware that `0b` binary notation isn't standard C but a non-standard extension. It may however get included in the upcoming C23 version of the C language. If portability is important, then avoid `0b`.

So if following best practices and using a STM32, your code should look something like:

```
#define MEANINGFUL_NAME_HERE 0x7u

uint8_t a = MEANINGFUL_NAME_HERE;
uint8_t b = (uint32_t)a << 1;
```

Comment: Why try to guess whether to use `uint16_t` or `uint32_t` depending on the platform when one can just as easily cast to `unsigned int` (or `unsigned` if you're really bothered by the extra keystrokes)?

Comment: @TooTea Because `(unsigned int)a` on a 32 bit MCU is non-portable to 8 or 16 MCUs. We can't know if the author of that cast intended to use 32 bit arithmetic or 16 bit arithmetic. Which obviously matters quite a lot in case of bit shifts, as one form means keep everything in bits 31 to 16 while the other form means discard everything in those bits. So the one using `(unsigned int)` is the one who forces people to guess.